# uploading user profile pics - guidelines

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want users to be able to upload images for profile pictures.

Are there any guidlines as to how this should best be handled?
eg - where to save the images? and folder structure to use.
- make it difficult for users to browse through everyones profile pics?

thanks.

Comment: It all depends on the architecture of your app - do you have a CDN? What kind of hosting are you using (standard shared hosting, Azure, etc.)? How will these images be used in the app?

Comment: its a standard asp.net mvc site, that will initially be on a shared hosting environment. The images will be shown next to  a users name when they comment etc.

Comment: Folder structure?  Are you under the impression that it matters?

Comment: @jfar was just wondering if there was a "best practice" for this. eg what to set for image names, storing resized thumbnails..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't mean to be a wet blanket if your into writing this yourself, but I would just use http://en.gravatar.com

But to answer your questions directly:

> Are there any guidelines as to how this should best be handled? eg - where to save the images? and folder structure to use. - make it difficult for users to browse through everyones profile pics?

Generally this is going to depend greatly on the setup of server environment.  Do you have multiple web servers? Do you have a database server you want to use?  Do you have an images only domain you want to use? etc.

The simplest approach is to write them to the file system and use code to retrieve them.  By not writing these files into your web directory you can be sure that users cannot use this to execute code or script on your server.  Useing an ASPX page to return the image content also allows you to relocate the image store at any time.

As for preventing browsing, I would just use a unique image identifier generated for each user.  BTW, I would not use the user's internal "ID" field; rather, create a new id just for images.

Answer (score 2):

If it is only to display a single user's picture, I would recommend to implement [Gravatar](http://gravatar.com) instead of your own approach. There are plenty of articles out there how to implemt Gravatar with ASP.NET MVC the best.

If you really want to have your own solution, I'd recommend to give all of the user's profile pictures a random file name (for example with a GUID "3F2504E0-4F89-11D3-9A0C-0305E82C3301.jpg").